# MPI-Умножение матриц ленточным способом с распределением строк

Tags: c++, матрицы, распараллеливание, mpi

Не совсем понятна постановка задачи: реализовать умножение матриц ленточным способом с распределением строк матрицы B. 
Если с распределением столбцов все легко-мы умножаем строку на столбец, то какой алгоритм тут хотят увидеть-я не представляю. Быть может, у кого-нибудь есть примеры кода?

Comment: Попробую предположить, что либо в задании опечатка, либо матрица `B` сначала транспонируется (есть такая форма оптимизации), либо вас просят реализовать достаточно сомнительный по эффективности и корявый по красоте алгоритм, просто чтобы проверить ваши способности.

Comment: Может быть, о последнем поподробнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кода у меня нет (и не будет), но могу предложить идею.

Матрица `B` разбивается построчно, а затем процедура скалярного умножения строк `A` на столбцы `B` реализуется параллельно через MPI.

Пусть у нас два процесса `S` и `T`. Тогда процесс `S` получает первую половину всех строк `B`, а процесс `T` - вторую. Далее, мы должны перемножить каждую строку матрицы `A` на каждый столбец матрицы `B` При этом половина столбца находится в `S`, а а вторая половина в `T`. Что делать, если нам надо перемножить строку `a` матрицы `A` на столбец `b` матрицы `B`, который уже разбит на две части b<sub>S</sub> и b<sub>T</sub>?

Очень просто строку `a` также разбиваем на две части a<sub>S</sub> и a<sub>T</sub>. a<sub>S</sub> идет в `S` и умножается на b<sub>S</sub>, одновременно с этим вторая половина строки a<sub>T</sub> идёт в `T`, и перемножается там на b<sub>T</sub>. Далее оба результата складываются, получается   результирующий элемент итоговой матрицы. И так нужно повторить для каждой строки и каждого столбца исходных матриц.

Надеюсь, мне никогда не придётся кодировать подобную ерунду, это непрактично и неэффективно.